# Artifactory - Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifactory

I am currently using Artifactory on-premise. I am planning to move to the cloud (AWS) and I don't understand the billing information (unit based)
Can anyone explain me what unit means in Artifactory ?

```
This software is priced along a consumption dimension.
Your bill will be determined by the number of units you use. Additional taxes or fees may apply.


JFrog Artifactory Cloud - Artifact Repository to Accelerate Your DevOps
Units   Cost
Base daily price    $13 / unit
20GB storage included - charge for each additional GB   $1.25 / unit
100GB data transfer included - charge for each additional GB    $1.25 / unit
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit refers to the consumption of specific data/time. In short:
Base daily price    $13 per day
20GB storage included - charge for each additional GB   $1.25 per GB
100GB data transfer included - charge for each additional GB    $1.25 per GB